# is it a bug in systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run my utility using `systemd`. The settings have the following values:

```
[Unit] 
Description="My Service"

[Service] 
WorkingDirectory=/etc/myutil

Group=user1 
User=user1

ExecStart=/bin/myutil

TimeoutSec=120 Restart=always

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So the service starts, but I need the `StandardInput=tty` parameter to be specified. If you can specify this parameter, the service will start by the root user, not by the specified user. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: maybe better for unix SE

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. Do you mean that systemd is not switching to your `user1` user if `StandardInput=tty` is specified? Or do you mean that your application is not starting at all? Also, why do you want to have stdin to be set to tty?

Comment: Yes, systemd is not switching to 'user1' user. 
I need stdin to be set to tty, because the application code is written so that it reads some commands from the console. If I do not redirect stdin, then the application is shutting down. I cannot change application's code(

Comment: I can’t reproduce this on systemd v238 – if I run `sudo systemd-run --wait -p StandardInput=tty-force -p TTYPath=$(tty) -p User=nobody id`, the user printed to the current TTY is `nobody`, not `root`.

(Note that this command will steal TTY ownership from your shell, with odd effects – for example, you will not be able to run `sudo` again in that shell. It’s probably best to do this in a fresh `tmux` window or something like that.)

Comment: "Note that this command will steal TTY ownership from your shell, with odd effects" - yes, I agree, it's very bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check permission for /dev/tty, and user1 groups

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty
$ id user1
```

I expect something like:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Jul  9 13:48 /dev/tty
$ id user1
uid=1234(user1) gid=10001(user1) groups=10001(user1),some_group(10002)
```

If I'm right You need add `user1` to tty group

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G tty user1
```

Now You should can use tty as user1.

Comment: I did as you said, but it did not work, the utility still starts by the root user, and if you remove StandardInput=tty, it starts by the specified user

Comment: So maybe try `ExecStart=/bin/su user1 -s /bin/sh -c /bin/myutil` If that not help, 
I have no more ideas :/

Comment: Thanks, but it not help me(